# Android app store rejecting over instagram api usage

Tags: android, google-play, instagram, instagram-api

I'm developing hybrid (Android, iOS) app which using Instagram api to fetch user general data without login by just providing any username.
I'm using following instagram apis:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=jack&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Then we store general info to our server, but now the problem is Android play store rejecting the app again and again.

Android play store giving following reason for rejection:
Your submission has been rejected for interfering with or accessing another service or product in an unauthorized manner. If this submission was an update to an existing app, the version published prior to this update is still available in Google Play. Please review section 4.4, of the Developer Distribution Agreement, then modify your app and resubmit. Additional details have been sent to your account owner's email address.

Please help me to find out the problem. Is instagram doesn't allow these api usage? Android don't allow to use these apis?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms of service of an app distribution channel and an image posting site, not programming. See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for more information about what is on-topic and off-topic for Stack Overflow regarding the Play Store and other app distribution channels. With respect to Instagram, ask Instagram.

Comment: Probably, you should do any direct call to Instagram API request from your server side instead with your own indirect URI request design from Android client side which passes only encrypted user name and access token to be secure. The URI response design shall send the encrypted data to be processed on your Android client side.